# Calculate of minimization in Lyapunov stability of ground states of nonlinear dispersive evolution equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Picture below is from

*Weinstein, Michael I.*, [**Lyapunov stability of ground states of nonlinear dispersive evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160390103), Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 39, 51-67 (1986). [ZBL0594.35005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0594.35005).

I don't know how to get the (3.1) and (3.2).  The (2.7) is 
$$
Q(\phi)=||\nabla \phi(\cdot+x_0,t )e^{i\gamma}-\nabla R(\cdot)||_{L^2}^2+E||\phi(\cdot+x_0,t)e^{i\gamma}-R(\cdot)||_{L^2}^2
$$
where $E$ is a constant. And $R$ is solution of 
$$
\Delta R - ER + |R|^{2\sigma}R=0.
$$
$\phi$ is solution of 
$$
i\phi_t(x,t) + \Delta \phi(x,t)+ |\phi(x,t)|^{2\sigma}\phi(x,t)=0.
$$
Besides, we have 
$$
\phi(x+x_0, t) e^{i\gamma} \equiv R（x） + w, ~~~~w=u+iv.
$$
In fact, I think I should do  perturbation over  $\phi$ in (2.7)， evenly
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}Q(\phi+ t\varphi)=0
$$
then, consider the real part and imaginary part I should get it. But obviously, in my way, I am far from (3.1) and (3.2).

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [image]